# filter on xml file loaded into jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to filter an xml file, which contains an dateFrom and dateTo. the records i want to show must be between the to dates.

Here is what I have in my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.get('InfotainmentContent.xml', function(d){

            function currentDate() {
                var d = new Date();

                var month = d.getMonth()+1;
                var day = d.getDate();

                var currentDate = d.getFullYear() + '-' +
                    ((''+month).length<2 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' +
                    ((''+day).length<2 ? '0' : '') + day;
            }



            $(d).find('mediaFile').each(function(){

                    var $mediaFile = $(this);
                    var imageurl = $mediaFile.attr('file');
                    var dateFrom = $mediaFile.attr('validFrom');
                    var dateTo = $mediaFile.attr('validTo');
                    var currentdate = currentDate();

                    if((dateFrom <= $.CurrentDate && dateFrom >= dateTo)) {
                            alert("true");
                            return true;
                        }

                    var html = '<li class="show"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="images/' + imageurl + '" width="1080" height="720" title="' + currentdate + '" alt="' + imageurl + '"/></a></li>';


                    $("ul").prepend($(html));
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

And my xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<infotainmentContent>
  <mediaFiles>
    <mediaFile file="1.jpg" fileType="PICTURE" durationInSeconds="10" validFrom="2014-04-23" validTo="2017-12-31" />
    <mediaFile file="2.jpg" fileType="PICTURE" durationInSeconds="10" validFrom="2014-04-23" validTo="2017-12-31" />
    <mediaFile file="3.jpg" fileType="PICTURE" durationInSeconds="10" validFrom="2014-04-23" validTo="2017-12-31" />
    <mediaFile file="4.jpg" fileType="PICTURE" durationInSeconds="10" validFrom="2014-04-23" validTo="2017-12-31" />
    <mediaFile file="5.jpg" fileType="PICTURE" durationInSeconds="10" validFrom="2014-04-23" validTo="2017-12-31" />
  </mediaFiles>
</infotainmentContent>
```

Please help and explain, or provide links to help
thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: What currently happens?

Comment: currently I just load all the data sets. know the dates are the same, but I don't know how to filter or only load those data where the current date is valid in the records date range.

It is the each.function I would like to have some help on. how to filter or only find those records which are valid.